# SharePoint extension command set

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online, sharepointframework

**SharePoint Modern: Is it possible to add an custom action using command set for a particular list or how to activate a custom action for specific list?** 
I am trying to develop a custom action for specific list but when I deployed in SharePoint tenant this custom action is added for all list(same type of list template).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my test solution to limit command set extension to specific list.

We could get current list title by `this.context.pageContext.list.title`.

```
@override
  public onListViewUpdated(event: IListViewCommandSetListViewUpdatedParameters): void {    
    const compareOneCommand: Command = this.tryGetCommand('COMMAND_1');
    if (compareOneCommand) {
      // This command should be hidden unless exactly one row is selected.
      compareOneCommand.visible = this.context.pageContext.list.title === 'MyList3';      
    }
  }
```

[One similar thread](https://www.itidea.nl/index.php/spfx-associate-listview-command-set-to-a-content-type/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.. You can check it with the list id, and if matches make command.visible == true